# Do Quantum Fluctuations happen evenly through universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology

I was wondering if Quantum Fluctuations are completely unpredictable, but do our observations tell us if these fluctuations happen evenly through space or are there regions where more quantum fluctuations occur than others?

If they are completely unpredictable and are forming at specific places, could this be reasoned why they are being created in these areas MORE than in other areas of our universe?

If possible can you present any observations or any evidence, for your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The [Casimir Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) constrains the available wavelength of quantum fluctuations within the space between two conducting plates. So the answer to your last question is "Yes" - some places have more than others. However, in free (flat) space the answer is probably "No". They are not totally unpredictable because otherwise people would not be able to (say) calculate the magnitude of the Casimir force. They are predictable from a statistical point of view, but like all quantum "things", individual measurement outcomes generally cannot be predicted with certainty.